# Evil-mode: delete until end of parens/quotes/brackets/etc

Tags: evil

Given the following (cursor at `|`), how can I delete the text `, int b`?

```
foo(int a|, int b);
```

I was hoping to find a motion similar to how "inner" works (eg `d i b`), but which only captures the right-hand side from the current position.

`d f )` also captures the found character, and I wanted to use this with all the usual motions.

Update: `d t )` does what I want in this case, but only works on the current line, so I would still like to know if there is a general motion to go the end of what can be done with the `inside` motion.

Comment: `dt)` can work across the current line after customizing `evil-cross-lines`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d ] )` should do what you're looking for `evil-next-close-paren`

Comment: I guess this is as good as it gets, but it doesn't work with `d ] }` for example.

Comment: @altschuler yeah, that appears to be missing. You can do `d i }` but that removes everything between the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can also in part depend on the major mode: in modes using SMIE for their indentation needs (e.g. Octave, SML, Prolog, Ruby, CSS), there's a good chance that `kill-sexp` (by default bound to `C-M-k`, no idea what that translates into for Evil) would do the trick (and in a case like `(int a|, int b, int c)` it would also kill `, int b`).

Comment: `kill-sexp` does something slightly different, it doesn't work with nested parens, so eg `foo(1|, bar(2))` deletes only `, bar`, where `d ] )` deletes `, bar(2)`.

Comment: @altschuler: You're mistaken: in SMIE-based modes it works differently.  But yes, in `c-mode` it works the way you describe (and actually even in `sm-c-mode`, which is based on SMIE, it also behaves the way you describe, since I had to disable that part of SMIE there because I had to use too many hacks which make it work OK for indentation but not for navigation).